# Azure SDK call returns 'Bad Request' a.k.a 400 for ResourceManagementClient::Resources::check_existence Method

Tags: ruby, api, azure, sdk, azure-resource-manager

I am using the 'azure_mgmt_resources -v 0.15.1' gem of Azure SDK. I am trying to check the existence of a particular resource on Azure.

This is my code

```
require 'azure_mgmt_resources'
include Azure::Resources::Mgmt::V2017_05_10
include Azure::Resources::Mgmt::V2017_05_10::Models

provider = MsRestAzure::ApplicationTokenProvider.new(
    'Tenant ID',
    'Client ID',
    'Client Secret')
credentials = MsRest::TokenCredentials.new(provider)

client = ResourceManagementClient.new(credentials)
client.subscription_id = 'Subscription ID'

response = client.resources.check_existence('Resource Group Name', 'Resource Provider', 'Parent Resource ID', 'Resource Type', 'Resource Name', 'API VERSION')
```

I am running the following two use cases

**1. When Resource Does Not Exist**

I pass false values to the check_existence method. For this I get back a 404 HTTP response code meaning that the
    resource does not exist, which is the expected response. This use
    case works fine.

**2. When Resource Does Exist**

I pass the correct values here and I get a 400 HTTP response code meaning that the request I sent is a bad one. I have used the same code as written above for both these cases.

My final analysis is that there is some sort of problem with the Azure server side that it is not returning a correct response when the resource clearly exists. Has anyone else encountered this error? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you check this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/tree/ARM-0.9.0/management/azure_mgmt_resources)?

Comment: You need configure authentication in your code.  `token_provider = MsRestAzure::ApplicationTokenProvider.new(tenant_id, client_id, secret)` `credentials = MsRest::TokenCredentials.new(token_provider)`

Comment: The correct credentials are being passed

Comment: Hi, could you share you code?

Comment: I am using the fog-azure-rm library for this. You can check it out here
Link => https://github.com/fog/fog-azure-rm